# angular directive using attribute cant get element inner html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying something with attribute instead of element in custom directive.

```
  <div dotdot>{{description}}</div>
```

I have created 'dotdot' directive to check length of description.

the code is below:

```
  .directive('dotdot', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope:true,
        link:function(scope,ele,attr){
            console.log(ele[0].innerHTML);// shows blank
            console.log(ele.html());     // shows blank                          
        }
    }
})
```

I am getting nothing in console (console.log(ele[0].innerHTML)) as I want length of text content for further operation.

Comment: I need to check that is there anything that would run the above code?  I mean using attribute and not using element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you restrict your directive to 'E' (E stands for Element). Which means only `<dotdot>{{ description }}</dotdot>` would work. Your provided HTML displays `dotdot` as an attribute. So `restrict: 'E'` should be `resrict: 'A'` (A stands for Attribute).

Secondly, why don't you pass the value of description to the directive through it's scope? Something along the lines of `<div dotdot="description"></div>`. It would be easier to `$watch` changes and act accordingly. Plus, if you keep your code in the link function like this, there may be a change your console.log will output `{{description}}`, because the digest cycle has not run yet. (which is not what you want).